# Pandas Merge DataFrames on similar dates (+-7 days)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge

I have two Pandas DataFrames and want to merge them on two attributes `key` and `date`, where `date` is a datetime and two rows should be merged, if the date of the second table is +-7 days close to the date in the first table.

Currently, I merge the data frames first and select the matching rows afterwards, but this is slow and results in a huge intermediate table:

```
res = pd.merge(left, right, on=['key'], how='inner')

mask = (
    ((res['date_x'] + pd.Timedelta(0, 'days')) <= (res['date_y'] + pd.Timedelta(7, 'days'))) &
    ((res['date_x'] - pd.Timedelta(0, 'days')) >= (res['date_y'] - pd.Timedelta(7, 'days')))
)

res = res.loc[mask]
```

Is there a faster way to reach the same result, like conditional merging?

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing a reproducible example, it sounds like you may be looking for the `merge_asof` function (if I understood your question correctly). https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html Should look something like:

```
pd.merge_asof(left, right, on="date", by="key", tolerance=pd.Timedelta(7, 'days'))
```